# Потратили НА рекламУ, но сэкономили НА рекламЕ?

Tags: управление, предлоги, словосочетания

Правильно я понимаю, что можно сказать *потратили **на** реклам**у*** или *сэкономили **на** реклам**е***, но не так, как сказано на изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Изображение = то, что изображено (рисунок, скульптура, фотография и т.п.), устар. Художественный образ.

Answer (score 4):

Вы абсолютно правы. Корректно: сэкономить на чем.

Вопрос

Как правильно: «экономить топливо» или «экономить на топливе»?

> Разные значения глагола экономить имеют разное управление.

Экономить **что –** расходовать экономно, бережно: экономить энергию, топливо, время; экономить деньги, экономить каждую копейку.

Экономить **на чем –** расходуя бережно, выгадывать на чем-нибудь:

> экономить на сырье, на топливе, на поездках, на обедах. Ср. также разговорное: На этом много не сэкономишь (т. е. не стоит экономить, выгоды не будет). Сюда также: экономить на спичках (разг. шутл.) – экономить ничтожно мало.
>   Экономить топливо - экономно расходовать топливо. Экономить на топливе – бережно расходуя топливо, получать выгоду (в затратах, например).

См.: Словарь трудностей русского языка . Ю. А. Бельчиков, О. И. Ражева. 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вариант **в данном случае**  - "сэкономили (на чём?) на рекламе", но  "сэкономить (на что?) на рекламу" также можно, это означает "найти деньги на рекламу, уменьшив другие расходы".

Например: "Иван трудами Софьи Андреевны **сэкономил на автомобиль** и жил, пожалуй, даже слишком хорошо".